# multiple representations of the same data within python class

Tags: python, neural-network

I am having trouble accessing and assigning new variables to an object that I've created. In a nutshell, I have created the object `Theta` that can hold multiple matrices (numpy), and I need that object to be accessible both in dictionary-of-matrices format, as well as a single-row-vector format.

For instance, when doing linear algebra operations (neural network application), I am able to access the individual matrices just fine and perform operations. However, it is easiest to pass those matrices on to other functions in the row vector format. I have another function within the class that takes in a row vector as input and re-makes all of the matrices, which I have omitted for brevity.

My issue is that I would like to access and assign new values by simply editing the row vector, without having to write a new function within the class that specifies index to index, and then the updated values. In short, I have two representations of the same data, and would like to be able to assign new values to one of the representations, and then the other representation is automatically updated as well.

I realize that I may be able to re-work the entire class to be architected differently to avoid these issues, but in general, I thought this might be a good question to ask. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

class Theta(object):
    def __init__(self, nn_specs, code = 'zeros'):
        self.specs = nn_specs
        self.matrices = {}
        if code == 'zeros':
            Theta.set_zeros(self)
        elif code == 'random':
            print('...setting random theta')
            Theta.set_random(self)

    def set_zeros(self):
        for i in range(len(self.specs)-1):
            self.matrices[i] = np.zeros((self.specs[i+1], (self.specs[i]+1)))

    def set_random(self, eps = 0.1):
        for i in range(len(self.specs)-1):
            self.matrices[i] = (np.random.rand(self.specs[i+1], (self.specs[i]+1)) * 2 * eps) - eps

    def get_flat(self):
        for i_theta in range(len(self.matrices)):
            if i_theta == 0:
                self.flat = self.matrices[i_theta].flatten()
            else:
                self.flat = np.concatenate((self.flat, self.matrices[i_theta].flatten()))
        return self.flat

test_theta = Theta((2,3,1), 'random')

print(test_theta.get_flat())

test_theta.get_flat()[2] = 3
#I AM NEEDING THIS TO CHANGE, with the third value being 3
print(test_theta.get_flat())
```